How do I interpret this CSS syntax?
I am attempting to override some CSS in an Internet theme and have encountered syntax that I have never seen before and that I do not understand. I give an example from the theme:
@media screen and(max-width: 768 px) {
    .wy-tray-container {
        bottom: auto;top: 0;width: 100 %
    }.wy-tray-container li {
        width: 100 %
    }
}

I see this pattern several times in the theme, sometimes 200-300 lines long and I have been unable to find anything that explains what is going on. Can anyone suggest some documentation that may explain this syntax. It looks like it is trying to add detail to a selector, but that is my only guess. Specifically, everything following }.wy is new to me. I cannot figure out what this CSS is trying to specify.

written like that, it's an invalid CSS

Yea looks like some parser choked on the hyphens and added spaces. }.wy is just a lack of whitespace which css doesn't care about.

@Temani Afif This has been taken from a large file - several hundred lines long and I  thought the sample was complete.

@Phix The original code was minified and I had to unminify it.

Confused on what you're asking... The white space between hyphens is not valid css. "max - width" should be "max-width" etc. When corrected it's a media query targeting certain classes.

@Pfif The spaces are not the problem. I have never seen nested CSS blocks as we have here and I don´t know how this should be interpreted.

The spaces are not the problem --> that's the problem everyone will see. If it's not the problem, fix it so we can see the real problem

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries

@Pfif Look at line 3 where there is a second {} block appended to the first. It is this that I do not understand.

I think the original CSS is supposed to look like this:
@media screen and(max-width: 768px) {
    .wy-tray-container {
        bottom: auto;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .wy-tray-container li {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

This can be minified to:
@media screen and(max-width:768px){.wy-tray-container{bottom:auto;top:0;width:100%}.wy-tray-container li{width:100%}}

There were a lot of spaces in your code that broke the CSS, but the syntax you find strange, like }.wy, is actually normal. It’s just the end of one rule and the start of a new selector.
If you're not familiar with media queries, check out this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

@rookdee I chose this sample because of its size. Are you saying that the CSS blocks are not nested? The fact that this is a media query is irrelevant.

@Jonathan rooklee is correct. There is no additional nesting. When a CSS block ends with }, anything non-whitespace that follows is the start of a new block, and is syntactically unrelated to the previous block. When writing un-minified code we would normally begin the new block on a new line, but this is not strictly needed for CSS parsers to understand that a new selector/block is beginning.

It appears that the unminifier has done a fine job of creating garbage. I checked the unmunified code and it made sens.
